# Using subprocess to log print statements of a command

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running a Transporter command, which prints a log of what is happening to the prompt.

How would I re-direct all the print statements to a separate file called `transporter_log.txt` in the same folder as the script is running from? Something like -

```
log_file = open(PATH, 'w')
subprocess.call(shlex.split("/usr/local//iTMSTransporter -m verify...")
log_file.write(...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the file as `stdout` parameter:

```
with open(PATH, 'wb') as log_file:
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, stdout=log_file)
```

The output of `cmd` is written to `log_file`.

Comment: `subprocess.call(cmd, stderr=log_file)`, since the print statements go in stderr

Answer (score 0):

What about using the redirect command (in on unix)?

```
your_python.py > /path/to/transporter_log.txt
```

Comment: It's a script that has a lot of commands, but for this specific command, I need to redirect the output (i.e., the print statements that it generates).